# `SqlServices.Install()` fails for Azure SQL database

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database, cloud

I am using the external executable (written in C#) to create the ASP.NET database tables, create the predefined roles, and the first user accounts. The same utility works just fine with the normal MS SQL (on premise). However, it fails when using the connection string for the cloud Azure SQL server. The core of the code:

```cs
// Extract the information from the connection string for the users database (aspnetdb).
string conString = DbUtil.GetUsersConnectionString();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cns = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(conString);

string SQLServerName = cns.DataSource;
string SQLServerUser = cns.UserID;
string SQLServerPassword = cns.Password;
string ASPNETdbName = cns.InitialCatalog;

// Create the aspnetdb database. No problem if it already exists.
if (SQLServerUser != "")
{
    // The variant for the explicit user name and password.
    SqlServices.Install(SQLServerName,
                        SQLServerUser, SQLServerPassword,
                        ASPNETdbName, SqlFeatures.All);
}
else
{
    // The variant for the trusted connection.
    SqlServices.Install(SQLServerName,
                        ASPNETdbName,
                        SqlFeatures.All);
}
```

The first variant for the name and password is used in the case. When debugging, the exception is thrown:

[image: the exception]

Roughly translated from Czech...

```
System.Web.HttpException: 'Cannot connect to the database of the SQL Server'
Inner Exception
ArgumentException: The keyword is not supported: b
```

The server name, user login, ASP.NET db name -- all of them look just normal. None of them contains the letter `b`. My wild guess is that the password is somehow weirdly processed. It contains semicolon, and the semicolon is followed by `B`, like this: `xxxxx;B=xxxxxxxx` (generated password, other characters replaced by `x`). I was given the password. I cannot try another one.

On the other hand, the connection string was copied from another web application, and only the database name was replaced. The following connection-string definition was taken from the config file -- the `connectionString="..."` below actually forms one line, here broken after semicolons only to make it more readable in the question text. **Notice**, that the "funny" **password had to be enclosed in single quotes**. That is because otherwise the semicolon inside caused the problems also in the other web application:

```
<add name="users_db_ConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx.database.windows.net;
                    Initial Catalog=xxxx_users;
                    Integrated Security=False;
                    User Id=xxxx;
                    Password='xxxxx;B=xxxxxxxx';"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The other web application that works with mostly the same connection string was created another way. The difference is that the ASP.NET users databae was transferred from on premise SQL via backup. The above `SqlServices.Install()` was called for the on premise SQL database (at the time, with different connection string and different password). The `SqlServices.Install()` was never tried on the cloud Azure SQL... until now.

My observation is that the single quoted password in the connection string causes no problems, when the connection string in the web application

```cs
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(appConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeoutSeconds;
    ...
}
```

However, it causes problems when the same is used through `SqlServices.Install()`.

Can you see any flaw in the code? Have you ever met something similar? Can anyone repeat the situation with similar password? Is it a bug in the `SqlServices.Install()`?